# addOne takes in a number as a parameter // and returns that numbers +1?

Tags: javascript

Function addOne returns undefined result...

```
const t = 5;
const b = 8;
function addOne () {
add (t + b);
return addOne;}
```

Pls help to get a sum of 5 + 8 with this function.

Comment: Can you add a tag with the programming language?

Comment: Sure, thats Java Script

Answer (score 0):

```
const t = 5;
const b = 8;
function addOne () {
  return t+b;
}
console.log(addOne()); //13
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are asking, since your method's name is not matching with your implementation. But here are some code that might help you:

```
const t = 5;
const s = 8; // Note that I have renamed the parameter's name
function addOne () {
    return s + 1;
}
function addOneToParameter(x) {
    return x + 1;
}
function addTwoConstants () {
    return t + s;
}
function addTwoParameters (a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
console.log(addOne()); // 9 (The constant 's' + 1)
console.log(addTwoConstants()); // 13 (The constant 's' + constant 't')
console.log(addTwoParameters(1,2)); // 3 (The first parameter + the second parameter)
console.log(addOneToParameter(4)); // 5 (The parameter + 1)
```

In your original question, you don't need to use a function to perform an addition of two integers. In other words, simply use '+' as operand. Furthermore, pay attention how to return a value from your function.